# I have followed the official tutorial of Django to make a poll app, but I couldn't go on

Tags: python, django

I have followed the tutorial to make the app, but after I changed the code from

```py
def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

to

```py
def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
```

(The code is at mysite\polls\models.py and the required changing action is on part 5 of the tutorial), I ran the `py manage.py test polls`, and then I got the error:
*

```
File "C:\Users\oliver\Desktop\TPA\mysite\polls\models.py", line 13
    now = timezone.now()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

*,
 and I also couldn't run the webserver, the error:
 *

```
File "C:\Users\oliver\Desktop\TPA\mysite\polls\models.py", line 13
    now = timezone.now()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

*

Could you please help me?
The platform: Windows 10
,Django version: 3.0.4
,Python version: 3.8.2
,The database is MySQL8.0
and
the tutorial:[tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/),
my code files:[file](https://github.com/Olivera-art/Django3-Poll-App.git).

Comment: Please post the error as text here instead of as an image. What error do you get when trying to run the webserver?

Comment: Have you tried searching for that Error Message - the last line of the error. You should be able to find an answer

Comment: the error itself explained it, you have indentation problem in your code at line 13. Check if you accidentally have a blank space

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code from github, It seems that you have some indentation errors at line 13 in file `mysite\polls\models.py`. Adding 4 spaces before line `now = timezone.now()` will fix your problem.

Comment: @RainPei Please mark ans as selected if it resolves your problem

Comment: Rahul Raut thank you for your reply, but the method didn't fix the problem. I have rewritten the code by hand(the former code was just copied from the internet), the issue was fixed. Rahul Raut thank you~